# Stress test for Nginx / Apache

Tags: apache, http, web, nginx, server

can you advice me the best tools and the best approaches to stress-testing Nginx and Apache?
I'd like to test which one is faster with some CMS's that I'm using.
Thanks!!

Comment: you may try [`ab`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apachebench-to-do-load-testing-on-an-arch-linux-vps) command line utility. [`siege`](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3936526/Load-Testing-and-Benchmarking-With-Siege.htm) might be useful as well

Comment: a small tip: while doing performance tests you should test both static and dynamic contents because results might be different.

Answer (score 2):

If you are stress testing CMSs, then neither Apache or Nginx will make a significant difference to performance. The bottleneck will almost certainly be upstream in your application. Possibly in your database if it's a CMS.

There are plenty of huge sites on both Nginx & Apache. With a bit of tuning both can handle large volumes of requests.